# Javascript/Angular is changing my number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was bored and was playing with angular filters, and I've noticed that angularjs will change the number if you use `| number` filter, which shouldn't affect my number in anyway, but somehow if I filter `9999999999999999` it will change it to `10000000000000000`, while if I filter `9999999999999998` it will leave it as it is `9999999999999998`.

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTDwol6mrTRtc5ffL5nJ?p=preview)

I am very curious and looking forward to know, what makes javascript/angularjs filter to change my number by 1 unit?

Comment: That is actually JS problem, try `var n = 9999999999999999;`

Comment: Welcome to floating point numbers.

Comment: Javascript only has 64-bit floats - and you've ran out of floating-point precision.

Comment: JavaScript really got your number on that one!

Comment: Why this happens? If a bank will use javascript, it could bring a bug to the whole system.

Comment: @PHPLover people who code with really big (and really small) numbers will run in to this type of problem quite often and there are libraries for most, if not all, languages to deal with these issues

Comment: Good js practices for money and other floating points where precision needs to be exact, is to not use floating point numbers, but multiply/divide everything back to an integer before doing maths. For numbers bigger than the limit, you can use strings and arrays to represent really big numbers. Writing a module to do maths with arrays is quite trival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually JS problem, try `var n = 9999999999999999`; and it is related to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER